# secure access token access with app fingerprint

Tags: security, spring-security-oauth2, app-id

Having a cordova app which authenticates a user via OAuth how could we make sure the provided access token and refresh token is only utilized in the device that requested the token or even better in the device and app that requested the token?

Currently the app will call the api in end points I have created to generate the token request, the flow is this:

1. API called
2. A request is generated with the client id and an encrypted payload and user is forwarded for authorizing the app to access the data
3. In the API if the user is not logged in will be asked to do so
4. Upon successful identification of the user the user is then presented with the requested scopes where the user can say wither yes or no I don't authorize for each requested scope
5. if the user accepts at least one scope then the token is granted and returned to the app

So my main question is in the 5th step
how can I uniquely identify x device or x device and app?

I am excluding sending the information via headers since if someone can get access to the phone and get a hold of the token then they probably can also get a hold of a device id and app id. So the idea is that if the data is sent via the headers of the request that it is somehow something that can't be forged by using any other device, is this possible?

Any options or is the current security I have in place enough?